# Axios result undefined inside render() method in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to do `axios.get()` request inside my react component:

I'm fetching this data from my mongo database and nodejs server is running on localhost:9000:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
export default class Home extends Component {
    state = {
        data : []
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        const {data} = await axios.get("http://localhost:9000/data")
            this.setState({data});
            console.log(this.state.data)        
    }
    render(){              
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
            <div>
                 {this.state.data[0]['title']}             
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Problem is that `{this.state.data[0]['title']}` says

> cannot read property 'title' of undefined

How can I correct this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share what your data looks like?

Comment: Between you don't have to use await if you are using .then

Comment: except you want to delay the code below

Comment: `this.state.data` is an array, not an object. So `const {array} = this.state.data;` won't work. Also, inside `componentDidMount`, you have mixed promise-chaining with `async-await` syntax. One more thing to note is that logging the `state` right after the call to `this.setState` will give you the previous state because state is updated asynchronously.

Comment: @Yousaf I made some changes, pls take a look. Thanks

Comment: As `componentDidMount` is called _after_ the initial render, `this.state.data[0]` will be `undefined` on initial render. So make sure that you only try to access the `.title` property when `this.state.data[0]` is not `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: @Yousaf when I'm using `this.state.data.length` it's giving length 3 and also `map()` method is also working fine, but why I'm not able to access individual elements and also earlier you said that on initial render its not `defined`, so how can I make it render initially . Thanks

Comment: You should be able to access the individual elements but only _after_ the initial render. Initially, the length of the `data` array is zero and `.map()` method will simply not execute because of an empty array but accessing a property on an array element that doesn't exists will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
 axios.get('http://localhost:9000/data')
 .then(function (response) {
 // handle success
  this.setState({data:response.data});
 console.log(response);
 })
   .catch(function (error) {
 // handle error
 console.log(error);
 })
.then(function () {
  // always executed
 });
```

and I think you must be used this like:

```
state = {
    data : [{
            _id:"",
            what:"",
            title:"",
            __v:0

           }]
}
 {this.state.data[0].title}
```